# Running a server in Parallels virtual machine. Is it possible for the host to access?

Tags: virtualization, parallels

I am running a web server in my Windows 7 guest OS, while I want to access it from my Mac host OS.
The web server is running and I can access it from my guest OS, but not from its host.

I'm using Parallels Desktop and I've tried to change the networking mode from shared, bridged, to host-only with no result.

This is for development sake, so I just need it to be at least accessible to my host OS.
Is this actually possible with Parallels, or should I keep an eye on other VM engine?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to put your guest into "bridged" networking mode. This will allow it to obtain an IP address on the same network as your host OS (from your router via DHCP or statically configured).

See [this](http://kb.parallels.com/4948):

> - **Shared Networking** – the recommended type of networking for the VM. Your virtual machine will share whatever network connection is used by
>     your Mac. You will be able to access the network from the VM as long
>     your Mac OS X is connected to the network. The only limitation of this
>     mode is that the VM is not visible from the external network
> - **Bridged Networking** – uses your network adapter. You should choose this mode if you want to access the VM from the external network.
>     Please keep in mind that your network configuration should allow using
>     DHCP to assign IP address for the VM, or you should obtain a static IP
>     for the VM and set it in the guest OS.

Comment: yes, it is working.. i tested in my ubuntu vm first...
in windows, initially is not working, I have to disable the firewall to make it works.
thanks Erik!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work when you don't have control over the router to ensure the two IPs can communicate, i.e.: Hotel, coffee shop, airport, etc.